# Python OSC, Query / Close active thread

Tags: python, sockets, osc

I'm using a relatively simple python execution, using OSC modules, in order to 'Send' code, from an application to an other.

```
import OSC
import threading

#------OSC Server-------------------------------------#
receive_address = '127.0.0.1', 9002

# OSC Server. there are three different types of server. 
s = OSC.ThreadingOSCServer(receive_address)


# define a message-handler function for the server to call.
def printing_handler(addr, tags, stuff, source):
    if addr=='/coordinates':
        print "Test", stuff

s.addMsgHandler("/coordinates", printing_handler)

def main():
    # Start OSCServer
    print "Starting OSCServer"
    st = threading.Thread(target=s.serve_forever)
    st.start()
main()
```

Runned once, will work just fine, an listen on port 9002.

But, runned twice, will return ERROR:

socket.error: [Errno 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

My goal is to:

1. Be able to query on active thread's port
2. Close them

I've tried the following...

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
result = s.connect_ex(('127.0.0.1', 900socket2))
print 'RESULT: ', result
s.close()
```

But giving me unsuccessful result. (Returns 10061 both for active and unactive port's thread)

Comment: How did you`terminate` the `OSCServer` and the `st.Thread`

Comment: I didn't. How should I?

Comment: Reading the OSC Document, there's nothing. Reading the source there is a `shutdown()`, give it a try. I assume no shutdown no freeing of port.

Answer (score 0):

> **Python » Documentation [socketserver.BaseServer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socketserver.html#socketserver.BaseServer.shutdown)**:

shutdown()

```
Tell the serve_forever() loop to stop and wait until it does.
```

server_close()

```
Clean up the server. May be overridden.
```